# Trouble pulling a github repo

Tags: git, github, repository, fork, pull

I have a fork to a github repo that I want to merge with the master. I do not know much about using git and a few months ago I forked when what I really wanted to do was branch. After I figured that one out, I just moved on and didn't think anything of it. But I checked the actual website of my account for the repo today and all of the work I've been committing has only been committing to the original account and not mine. My commits stop months ago when I forked.

I want to know how to make it so that my account will have the same code as the original.

I tried a going to the original account's repo and doing a pull request. That gave me -

```
Oops! The master branch is already up-to-date with master — maybe you want to try something else?
```

I don't understand what it is comparing to get the result that our codebase is the same.

I tried this terminal command -

```
git pull https://github.com/jdannas/irobot_driver master
```

Which gave me basically the same thing -

```
From https://github.com/jdannas/irobot_driver
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Here is a screenshot of the graph. All of the commits are mine, but you can see that my timeline stops in late August and the commits go to the original. [image]

Can someone help me figure out what I need to do to fix this? I was directed to http://progit.org/book/, which I will certainly be reading in meantime and throughout the future, but it would be great if I could get this issue resolved without reading for hours. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put your code into the sterlings repo, you need to do a pull request via the GitHub UI (button's top right in your screenshot).  This will then ask the maintainer to merge in your code.

You need to then ensure that you're working with the correct repo locally.  The most bulletproof way of doing this is to blow away your local copy (backup!) and re-clone from sterlings.

Comment: I tried the top right button and it tells me that mine is up to date. I will try the second suggestion though.

Comment: Okay, so I deleted everything in the folder. Then did git clone <link to my(sterling) git repo>. I changed a little small thing and committed to test, but it still only committed to the other one. Did I interpret "blow away your local copy (backup!) and re-clone from sterlings." wrong?

Comment: OK - that wasn't clear.  So you need jdannas to create the pull request.

Comment: He was able to pull my repo and got "29 files changed, 866 insertions(+), 776 deletions(-)"...but whenever I commit and push, it is still not updating my repo. The graph also did not change.

Comment: Would I be able to just checkout the jdannas repo again?

Comment: Okay, I just deleted everything in the folder...cloned sterlingm repo...replaced all the files with the code from jdannas repo...and commit/push and it worked. Now last question - is there a way to commit to both repos at once? I have been git commit -a -m ".". I think -a meant all, but now I'm only committing to sterlingm